# VHDL - Can you produce an output corresponding to the input if the input changed in the same clock cycle?

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, vhdl, hdl

In VHDL, if we have a system where the output changes depending on a variable that changes with the input. Say the output has 2 modes and an input switches between them. In the same clock cycle, can we check whether the input has changed (check if a button is pressed), store current input state *and* produce an output corresponding the input in the same clock cycle (if the output was changed in the same clock cycle)?

Comment: Yes. <Filler text>

Comment: Yea.........draw on a paper with flipflop and inputs ....then the vhdl code automatically comes to u

Comment: @MITURAJ *"then the vhdl code automatically comes to u"* You are an optimist I see. For some people it never comes.....

Comment: hahaa ;)  ..........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, sure. You'll have to store the previous state anyway so you can detect when it changes. As for generating an output, you can either update that on the next clock cycle or generate it combinatorially in the same cycle.